# list indices must be integers or slices, not str error when parsing json request

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Code

```
data = response.json() 
parsedValueLookup = data['users'] 
userName = parsedValueLookup['username'] 
userID = parsedValueLookup['id']
```

line 4 is causing the issue, any solutions?

Here is my JSON

```
{'code': 200, 'users': [{'id': 18937, 'username': 'TestUser'}]}
```

Comment: Can you show your JSON, please? Line 3 and 4 are doing the same thing incorrectly, if thats your error

Comment: [{'id': 18937, 'username': 'TestUser'}] @cricket_007

Comment: That has no `users` value. Show the `data` value from the code, please. And [edit] your question with it

Comment: edited :) data is from response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *index* the list using integers, as the error hints at.

```
userName = users[0]['username'] 
userID = users[0]['id']
```

Or, use a loop.

```
for user in users:
    userName = user['username'] 
    userID = user['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

parsedValueLookup = data['users'] returns a list - you are treating it like a dictionary - hence your error message